# Alignment problem with editable and non editable labels of pop up

Tags: css, alignment

I have a pop up which opens as all label type or editable type based on the condition.
When I open the pop up as editable, the table is set to center and values are properly
aligned. When I open the same in non editable mode, the values are more moved to the left.

I have uploaded both to `JSFiddle` for analysis. Please help

Pop up with **editable** condition

http://jsfiddle.net/gr2022s/C9BZJ/

Pop up with **non editable** condition

http://jsfiddle.net/gr2022s/C9BZJ/1/

I had done a workaround by adding `<blockquote>` tag to one of the label but the problem seems to be
the label is moved towards right from the others.

Comment: ooops!!!! sorry.....can you check again now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is quite simple :

You never define any width for any `<td>`. So your `<table>` will scale each **column** according to the largest **td** content. And since your `<input type="text />` is way larger than the simple text `Ad Hoc`, the editable table *seems* more centered...

Try this to test it :

```
<table border="1" width="300px">
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" width="300px">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" width="300px">
    <tr>
        <td>aaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or see [your updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C9BZJ/8/).